# What causes Scripting Error 000714 in ArcGIS when using GetParametersAsText?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I am trying to create a script tool in ArcGIS 10.2 in order to incorporate into a model. The script needs to incorporate three inputs which i've built using GetParameterAsText function then setting up the corresponding links within ArcGIS Script Tool Wizard.

However, when I run the script I get **[ERROR 000714](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp00000019000714)** (see below). Not sure how to handle this error or why it isn't working to begin with.

```
import arcpy

inFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outFCName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
outFC = outFolder + "\\" + outFCName

try:
    if arcpy.Exists(outFC):
        arcpy.Delete_management(outFC)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outFolder,outFCName,"POLYLINE","#","DISABLED","DISABLED",inFC)
    arcpy.AddField_management(outFC,"inFID","LONG","#","#","#","#","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","#")

    iCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFC, ["inFID","SHAPE@"])

    print "Starting!"

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inFC,["OID@", "SHAPE@"]) as sCursor:
        for row in sCursor:
            inFID = row[0]
            # Print the current multipoint's ID
            #
            # print("Feature {0}:".format(row[0]))
            partnum = 0

            # Step through each part of the feature
            #
            for part in row[1]:
                # Print the part number
                #
                # print("Part {0}:".format(partnum))

                # Step through each vertex in the feature
                #
                prevX = None
                prevY = None
                for pnt in part:
                    if pnt:
                        # Print x,y coordinates of current point
                        #
                        # print("{0}, {1}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y))
                        if prevX:
                            array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(prevX, prevY),
                                                 arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y)])
                            polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)
                            iCursor.insertRow([inFID,polyline])
                        prevX = pnt.X
                        prevY = pnt.Y
                    else:
                        # If pnt is None, this represents an interior ring
                        #
                        print("Interior Ring:")
                partnum += 1

    del iCursor

except Exception as e:
    print e.message
    arcpy.AddError(e.message)

print "Complete"
```

Here is the error:

```
Executing: SplitLines "F:\Extra Data\Prop Frontage\test_for_py.shp" tester.shp "F:\Extra Data\Prop Frontage"
Start Time: Thu Jan 23 11:38:46 2014
Running script SplitLines...
ERROR 000714: Error in script SplitLines.
Error in executing: cmd.exe /C F:\MASTER~2  "F:\Extra Data\Prop Frontage\test_for_py.shp" "tester.shp" "F:\Extra Data\Prop Frontage"

Failed to execute (SplitLines).
Failed at Thu Jan 23 11:38:46 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.16 seconds)
```

Comment: Just a thought, but shouldn't `outFC = outFolder + outFCName` be `outFC = outFolder + "\\" + outFCName` and come after the `GetParameterAsText(2)` line?

Comment: I tried moving that after the final GetParameterAsText(2) but it didn't solve the error issue.

Comment: Are you running this script from ArcMap, ArcCatalog, or as a standalone *.py script from the command prompt?  Can we assume that your filename is "SplitLines" by reading the error report?  Have you tried running it in DEBUG mode to know which line the error occurs on?

Comment: SplitLines is the tool name created in ArcMAP. The script was imported into their tool creator in order to integrate into a model. 

The Model was running perfectly until implementing the GetParameterAsText fields.

Comment: What parameters did you assign for the GetParameterAsText functions?

Comment: @Aaron, seconded.  I am wondering if arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) is a string parameter.  Also, will the output be a shapefile or a a GDB FC.  I know you say FC, but they get used interchangeably sometimes.  If (1) is a string and you want to output a SHP, you will need to add a '.shp' either during the model run, or hard code it in the script after you create the outFC variable.

Comment: the output is a SHP (FC is likely not the right term but it was just for my self). 1: Input Shape File 2: Name of the output Shp file (I add .shp while typing in the name) 3: Out put directory.

Comment: Perhaps I was in error in using "AsText", I'm guessing it should simply be GetParameter()?

Comment: ``GetParameter`` returns an object, ``GetParameterAsText`` returns a string.

Comment: Understandable. I shall try altering that portion of the code. I know my error has to be in getting the parameters because if I hard code the variables it work perfectly.

Comment: you should use the full path of inFC when you use it inside a model.

Comment: How so? As an input, wouldn't inFC take the full path? If I browse to my file and select it, would it not take the entire path?

Comment: It will only get exactly what's in the box, if that doesn't include the full path your script will not get it. You should try to enter the full path instead and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: The Comments on this Question have run for a while, and now it is not clear whether you have a solution or not.  If you do have a solution, would you be able to flag us to re-open and write up an Answer.  If not, can you use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with the current state of your focussed Question, please?